# How to Remove Error Check for Git Hub Copilot solutions Tab

Tags: visual-studio-code, github-copilot

**My Vs code Check Error Git Hub Copilot solutions Tab, How to Disable it, Thanks** :
[vs code error Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/cWZBt.png)

Comment: can you close it ?

Comment: yes, but when close tab, err still display in problems tab

Comment: Can you run react project? if yes, dont worry about err in copilot tab

Answer (score 2):

You need to deactivate Copilot globally on your VS Code IDE and then activate it again.

Hope this helps.

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. Once you have sufficient [reputation](https://stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation) you will be able to [comment on any post](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/comment); instead, [provide answers that don't require clarification from the asker](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/214173/why-do-i-need-50-reputation-to-comment-what-can-i-do-instead). - [From Review](/review/low-quality-posts/32189921)

Comment: @slideshowp2, Is my answer now understandable? I'm curious as to how can you say this does not provide an answer. I experienced the same problem and this simple thing fixed it for me.